# How to merge series of ffmpeg commands?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I am using the following series of commands to produce a video. Is it possible to merge all or some of those commands?

First, I extract some parts of the video, let's say three:

```
ffmpeg  -y -ss 1666 -i "in.mkv" -t 10 -codec:v ffvhuff  "tmp/2.EC.avi"
ffmpeg  -y -ss 1676 -i "in.mkv" -t 941 -codec:v ffvhuff  "tmp/3.EC.avi"
ffmpeg  -y -ss 2617 -i "in.mkv" -t 10 -codec:v ffvhuff  "tmp/4.EC.avi"
```

Then I change the playback speed of some of them, let's say #3's speed is doubled. I also place a small image on the video to indicate the speed is changed:

```
ffmpeg  -y -i tmp/3.EC.avi -i ff64.png \
    -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS,overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w-10):10[v];[0:a]atempo=2[a]" \
    -codec:v ffvhuff -map "[v]" -map "[a]" "tmp/3.EC.x2.avi"
```

Then, I merge all those into a single `.avi`:

```
ffmpeg \
    -i "tmp/2.EC.avi" -i "tmp/3.EC.x2.avi" -i "tmp/4.EC.avi" \
    -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" \
    -codec:v ffvhuff  -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -y \
    "tmp/out.avi"
```

Finally, I create a `.mkv` file with the parameters that I need:

```
ffmpeg  -y \
    -i "tmp/out.avi" \
    -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 -c:a aac -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    "out.mkv"
```

I want to execute the same process with less number of commands. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not script:

```
ffmpeg \
-ss 666 -to 671 -i "input.mkv" \
-ss 671 -to 762 -i "input.mkv" \
-ss 762 -t 5 -i "input.mkv" \
-i logo.png \
-filter_complex "
[1:v]setpts=PTS/2[v];
[1:a]atempo=2[a];
[v][3]overlay=W-w-10:10[v];
[0:v][0:a][v][a][2:v][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1
" -c:v h264 -crf 18 -c:a aac -q:a 5 "out.mkv"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a script is your best bet here.

**Extract**

The first task sounds like it has specific perimeters that change with each project. You could write an interactive script that asks you how many videos you want to cut then asks for the start and duration times, but would that really be easier than copy and pasting your original command a few times? barely.

**The rest:**

```
#!/bin/bash

#Slow Playback

# Iterate over every .avi file in current directory and ask for playback speed
for file in *.avi
do
    if [ -f "$file" ]
    then
        read -p "Enter a speed value for $file: " speed
        echo "Processing $file ..."
        ffmpeg -i "$file" -filter:v "setpts=$speed*PTS" "slow_$file"
        echo "Done processing $file"
        mv "$file" trash/
    fi
done

echo "All files processed"

# Merge

# Create an array of inputs from cd
inputs=(*.avi)
# concat the files in array
ffmpeg -i "concat:${inputs[*]}" -codec:v ffvhuff -y "merged.avi"

# Convert to mkv
ffmpeg -y -i "merged.avi" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 -c:a aac -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p "final.mkv"
```

Make that script executable `chmod +x my_script.sh` and move it to the directory you want to work in.